# RFEM: Equilibrium over plate section

Tags: finite-element, solid-mechanics

I'm calculating a simple plate arrangement in RFEM:

[image]

The plate has dimensions of 1m X 1m, thickness of 50mm. Elastic modulus of the material is 205000.0 N/mm2, Poisson's ratio is 0.3.

The plate is loaded in the middle, with 10kN load. Self-weight has been neglected. The plate is simply supported at 4 corners:

[image]

According to RFEM, the support reactions at the corners is 2.5kN, which at the 4 corners adds to 10kN as expected.

I took a section cut 200mm from one edge (shown in the first picture) and studied the results.

The internal moment m_y looks like this:

[image]

The section average is reported as 1kNm/m, meaning that the total moment across the 1m section is 1kNm. A simple check calculation can be done: since the distance from this section to the edge is 200mm, and we have total of 5kN at the two corners, we have 5kN * 0.2m = 1kNm. This matches the section diagram result and the section is at equilibrium.

The shear force in z-direction looks like this:

[image]

The total shear is reported as 3.805kN. **This does not seem to make the section at equilibrium with the supporting forces.** Should the total section shear be equal to the reaction forces, which are a total of 5kN?

Would anyone know if I am misunderstanding something about plate theory in general, or is my mistake something in the software itself?

According to [RFEM documentation](https://www.dlubal.com/en/downloads-and-information/documents/online-manuals/rfem-5/08/15), the shear force V_y is calculated by integrating the shear stresses in y-face of an element, into z-direction, so the internal force in question should be correct.